# How to offer free DApps for users without any barriers?

Tags: gas, json-rpc, light-clients, fees, cors

How to offer decentralized applications or services for users without introducing any barriers like

- running a full ethereum node?
- enabling rpc api on the node?
- explaining the user which rpc cors domain to set?
- telling the user to buy ether to pay the gas fees?

I want to create a service, running on ethereum infrastructure but the user should not be limited by hurdles like buying ether to interact with the blockchain.

Is this possible to offer free services, where for instance a smart contract pays for the user's transaction fees?

Comment: How would you limit usage? Free is always abused.

Comment: We've gone so far. There's account abstraction now & gasless transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any decentralized service you can offer an additional centralized server to access the decentralized service. That means that people who want ease-of-use can use it via the centralized server will people who care about using it in a decentralized way can access it via talking to the ethereum blockchain directly.